# Catch Java exceptions in Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, exception

Im in the place that I have to develop an interface in Java to work with from matlab. However I currently don't have access to matlab.
For using the interface and handling errors I'd like to use exceptions, as they would be easy to use.

Is it possible to catch a java exception in matlab?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, [here's how](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.exception.javaexception-class.html) (see "Examples").

Because StackOverflow requires minimum 30 chars in the message body, this statement serves as filler.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to catch a java exception using the MATLAB `try/catch` block like this:

```
j = java.lang.String('foo');
try
    j.substring(-2);
catch E
    fprintf('Caught this: %s\n', getReport(E));
end
```

which results in this:

```
Caught this: Java exception occurred: 
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
```